# Jtoken containing DateTime tostring unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this json:

```
{
  "sku": "articlenumber",
  "lastModified": "2022-05-06T10:07:23.934Z",
  "quantity": 20
}
```

I have to send the exact value of "lastModified". As I don't have to do any operations on this value I decided to store it in a string. The problem is casting the JToken to string gives me a completely different formatting:

```
string foo = (string)json["lastModified"]
/// 05/06/2022 10:07:23
```

How can I get the actual recieved raw string out of the json?

what I already tried:
parsing the data into a datetime object and serializing with custom settings like so

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{  
    DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffZ",
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind
};
```

This gives me a correctly formatted string but zeroes the miliseconds.

```
/// "2022-05-06T10:07:23.000Z"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var json = "{\"sku\": \"articlenumber\",\"lastModified\": \"2022-05-06T10:07:23.934Z\", \"quantity\": 20}";
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None };
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json, settings);
var result = data.Value<string>("lastModified");
```

- The trick here is the `DateParseHandling.None`
- The weird part is to use `DeserializeObject` to get `JObject`

---

You can use `data["lastModified"].Value<string>()` as well if you wish.

Comment: [Working demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ysUTmL)